# How to implement angled surface?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics, rotation

I'm trying to implement 2D platformer game inspired by [N game](http://www.thewayoftheninja.org/nv2.html).
 But the problem is I have no idea how to implement something like this:

[image] and [image]

I have two ideas of how this could be implemented, but I don't know if they are somewhere near truth:

1. Pick two nearby pixels of the surface, draw a line between them and then rotate player so his height was perpendicular to that line.
2. Check if the bottom-left pixel is touching surface and bottom right is not, rotate player so bottom-right pixel would touch the surface too.

Comment: Metanet Software (the folks behind the *N* game) have written [a tutorial to how they did collision detection in *N*](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html).

Answer (score 1):

i did something similar a while back, it's not that hard, one very easy and understandable way is :
1- rotate everything! means every line every object, so everything is simply flat!
2- calculate velocity, gravity, friction and ... anything you like ! just the way you always do in a flat and without rotation world
3- rotate everything back the way it was !
there is also using physic libraries which is a bit complicated since you need to study the samples and learn how to use the library !
if this is your first attempt on making a game with motions and ... i suggest you take a look at :
1 - [http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Actionscript-3-0-Animation-Making/dp/1590597915](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590597915)
2- [http://www.amazon.com/AdvancED-ActionScript-Animation-Friends-Learning/dp/1430216085/ref=pd_sim_14_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=1Y0G31E4VKEY4FZ43HPM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430216085)
i found a source code that i wrote a long time ago
it uses the 3 step i mentioned above

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class AngleBounce extends Sprite
    {
        private var ball: Ball;
        private var line: Sprite;
        private var gravity: Number = .3;
        private var bounce: Number = -.6;

        public function AngleBounce()
        {
            init();
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            ball = new Ball();
            addChild(ball);
            ball.x = 100;
            ball.y = 100;
            line = new Sprite();
            addChild(line);
            line.graphics.lineStyle(1);
            line.graphics.lineTo(300, 0);
            line.x = 50;
            line.y = 200;
            line.rotation = 30;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        }

        private function onMouseDown(event:Event):void
        {
            ball.startDrag();
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onMouseUp(event:Event):void
        {
            ball.stopDrag();
            ball.vx = 0;
            ball.vy = 0;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            line.rotation = (stage.stageWidth/ 2 - mouseX) * .1;
            ball.vy += gravity;
            ball.x += ball.vx;
            ball.y += ball.vy;

            if (ball.x < 0 + ball.width / 2 || ball.x > stage.stageWidth - ball.width / 2)
            {
                ball.vx *= -1;
            }

            if (ball.y < 0 + ball.height / 2 || ball.y > stage.stageHeight - ball.height / 2)
            {
                ball.vy *= -1;
            }

            var bounds:Rectangle = line.getBounds(this);
            if(ball.x > bounds.left && ball.x < bounds.right)
                {
                var angle: Number = line.rotation * Math.PI / 180;
                var sin: Number = Math.sin(angle);
                var cos: Number = Math.cos(angle);

                var x1: Number = ball.x - line.x;
                var y1: Number = ball.y - line.y;
                var vy1: Number = cos * ball.vy - sin * ball.vx;
                var y2: Number = cos * y1 - sin * x1;

                if (y2 > -ball.height / 2 && y2 < vy1)
                {
                    y2 = -ball.height / 2;

                    var x2: Number = cos * x1 + sin * y1;
                    var vx1: Number = cos * ball.vx + sin * ball.vy;

                    vy1 *= bounce;

                    x1 = cos * x2 - sin * y2;
                    y1 = cos * y2 + sin * x2;
                    ball.vx = cos * vx1 - sin * vy1;
                    ball.vy = cos * vy1 + sin * vx1;
                    ball.x = line.x + x1;
                    ball.y = line.y + y1;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "onEnterFrame" is where the magic and the 3 steps happens, if you can not understand the code or have any question, please let me know